# PowerShell - Save output to a text file with dd-mm-yyyy added to the name of the file

Tags: powershell

The below script will run daily, task schedule, need help in saving the output to a text file e.g. something like

SPContentDatabaseStatus_17-10-2013.txt and saved in a folder named Reports.

Running the below

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -EA silentlycontinue

$webapps = Get-SPWebApplication
foreach($webapp in $webapps)
{
Write-Host - $webapp.url -Fore Green
$sites = $webapp.sites
foreach($site in $sites)
{
if($site.readlocked -eq $False -AND $site.WriteLocked -eq $False -AND $site.ReadLocked -eq $False){Write-Host $($site.url): "Not locked"}
if($site.readlocked -eq $False -AND $site.WriteLocked -eq $True -AND $site.ReadLocked -eq $False){Write-Host $site.url: "Adding content prevented: $($site.LockIssue)"}
if($site.readlocked -eq $False -AND $site.WriteLocked -eq $True -AND $site.ReadLocked -eq $True){Write-Host $site.url: "Not locked: $($site.LockIssue)"}
if($site.readlocked -eq $null -AND $site.WriteLocked -eq $null -AND $site.ReadLocked -eq $null){Write-Host $site.url: "No access"}
}
Write-host ""
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$Today = [string]::Format( "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", [datetime]::Now.Date )
$TranscriptFileName = "SPContentDatabaseStatus_$Today.txt"
Start-Transcript -path $TranscriptFileName -append
..... 
Stop-Transcript
```

Modify your path accordingly...

I should mention however that transcripts/ write-host doesnt work so well if your scripts are being run using the task manager. Another option would be...

```
function Log($msg)
{
    $msg
    $msg | Out-File $TranscriptFileName -Append
}
```